# File not found in Xcode project folder

Tags: ios, xcode

Why compiler looking for file only in project folder, and no in subfolder.

```
ERROR: Can't find /Users/kukodajanos/Workspace L/PFB2/crossfeed_connecting.png
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with exit code 1
```

This is the project folder: `/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace L/PFB2`
but file is not in root but in `/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace L/PFB2/PFB/`

I am after a merge. Why Xcode is not enough smart to look for file in subdirectory? Anyway all class files .h, .m, resources are stored there.

Comment: You need give exact file path else it wont work.

Comment: may be help you https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html

Comment: `build >settings -> Search Path -> User Header Search Paths ->` set Root Path `"${PODS_ROOT}/"`

Comment: What is `PODS_ROOT`? If I do not use cocoa pods, is this still valid?